# Capturing namespace variable in lambda

Tags: c++, lambda

I am trying to pass the namepace variable to lambda and get the variable incremented from lambda function.

This is my program

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>

using namespace std;
namespace np
{
    int data = 0;
}

int data1 = 0;

int main()
{
    // cout << np::data <<endl;        // compiler error :unable to capture the variable within namepspace
    // [&np::data](){ np::data++;};
    // cout << np::data <<endl;
    
    cout << data1 <<endl;  //unable to increment the global variable from lamba
    [&data1](){ data1++;};
    cout << data1 <<endl;
    
}
```

I have two questions:

1. Why am I not able to increment the global variable from lambda ?
2. Why lambda is unable to capture variable within namespaces ?

Comment: Try this instead:  auto value = [&]()
 {
  np::data++;
 }; value(); Now the value of data will be incremented. To answer your first question: a variable with static storage duration cannot be captured in lambda

Comment: You have a lambda expression, but you are not invoking its result, so obviously its code will never execute. BTW, there's no need to explicitly capture globals.

Comment: You never invoke the said lambda.

Comment: `[&data1](){ data1++; };` is also ill-formed. (Read the compiler warning!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a full answer, but I hope it will help.

The idea of lambda functions is to capture local variables, not global variables. If you want to increase a global variable, you don't need to capture it:

```
[](){ data1++; np::data++;} // no problem
```

The "feature" of capturing global variables is a bit confusing, and it exists only (my guess) because they are visible in the function's block:

```
int data1;

int main()
{
    int data_local;
    [&data1,        // superfluous, but works anyway
     &data_local    // useful
    ](){data1++; data_local++};
}
```

Since namespaces are impossible locally, global variables in namespaces cannot be captured - this would be a useless feature. In my opinion, capturing global variables outside namespaces is useless too, and is confusing in addition, so it would be better to emit an error if a lambda captures such a global variable. Compilers actually emit a warning for this case.

Finally, the code above only "declares" a lambda function (actually, it only "mentions" it - there is no way to use this "declared" lambda). To call it, append a list of arguments:

```
[](){data1++;}; // "declaration"
[](){data1++;}(); // call
```

Comment: `&data1` is not superfluous, it just doesn't compile.

Comment: Both [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c313623c56847b0b) and clang reject it with `-pedantic-errors`.